# Django queryset for Status field

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

i have a status field at my model  that can have Waiting, Accepted, Rejected. How can i filter for the status?

I only want to filter for "Waiting" and order by "-pk"

so how do i combine these two?

Thanks and BR

Comment: `CategoryRequests.objects.filter(status='Waiting').order_by('-pk')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list_requests = CategoryRequests.objects.filter(status='Waiting').order_by('-pk')
```

Simple as That!!
Note You can chain the functions like

```
model.objects.filter(key=value).order_by('key2').filter(key3=value).values('key')
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

`QuerySet`s are constructed by "chaining" methods. Each method creates a new queryset, that is typically a modified version of the previous one. For example a `.filter(..)` will add a condition to a `WHERE` (and might add extra `JOIN`s, etc.).

So you can create such queryset with:

```
CategoryRequests.objects.filter(status='Waiting').order_by('-pk')
```

Of course this only works given the status *has* a `'Waiting'` value.